# How do I set the variable to an incoming argument in java?

Tags: java

import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

//COMPLETE THE TEMPLATE BELOW

public class Problem3_1{

```
//complete this class, called Problem3_1, with the following items: 

//1. Declare four attributes, name, age, height, and weight of types String and int-s.  
//Write a constructor for this class that initializes ONLY the name, age, and height to three incoming arguments,  
//and sets the weight to always be -1 (the latter is not an incoming argument).
String name;
int age;
int height;
int weight;
Address address;
public Problem3_1(String name, int age, int height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
    weight = -1;
}

void setAddress(int number, String street) {
    address = new Address(number, street);
}




//2. Imagine there is a class called Address that you have access to (it's below).  
//Its constructor takes an integer street number and a String street. Add an attribute called address to  
//the Problem3_1 class, and create a method called setAddress that sets the attribute to the incoming argument.  

public static class Address{ 

    int number; 
    String street; 

    public Address(int number, String street){ 
        this.number = number; 
        this.street = street; 
    }
}
```

}

So why is the code saying I have this void info in the wrong location?  Where's the correct location for it?  Or why can't it be "applied"?

PS: The error I get:

> Problem3_1.java:82: setAddress(int,java.lang.String) in Problem3_1
>   cannot be applied to (Problem3_1.Address)
>           p.setAddress(a);

Test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    /*Below are tests that will check if you completed the code above correctly; if  
      your code doesn't compile, you'll need to fix those errors first. 

      DO NOT WRITE CODE BELOW THIS POINT 
    */ 

    int failed = 0; 

    Problem3_1 p = new Problem3_1("Jane", 22, 65); 

    if (p.name.compareTo("Jane") == 0 && p.age == 22 && p.height == 65 && p.weight == -1) 
        System.out.println("Test 1 passed!"); 
    else{ 
        failed ++; 
        System.out.println("Please check your code for question 1! "); 
    } 

    Address a = new Address(12, "Fairfax Dr"); 
    p.setAddress(a); 

    if (p.address == a) 
        System.out.println("Test 2 passed!"); 
    else{ 
        failed ++; 
        System.out.println("Please check your code for question 2! "); 
    }         


    if (failed > 0) 
        System.out.println(systemCall("Failed")); 
    else{ 
        System.out.println("GREAT WORK! EVERYTHING PASSED!"); 
        System.out.println(systemCall("Nice")); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: You forgot the address parametar in your setAdress function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, pass Address class as parameter.

```
void setAddress(Address s)
```

Since Address in a static nested class, but you have declared Address as `String` in your Problem3_1 class file. So you will need to concat the values manually like

```
void setAddress(Address s) {
        //address = s;

        address = s.number + " , " + s.street;
    }
```

This should work, if you're creating and passing the values correctly.

Example:

```
    Problem3_1 a = new Problem3_1("name1",20,5);
    Problem3_1.Address a_address= new Problem3_1.Address(20,"1st street");
    a.setAddress(a_address);

    System.out.println(a.address);
```

This should print your desired output if you have override the toString() method in outer class as well as inner class.

**UPDATE**

http://ideone.com/rS20uZ - Check here for full code and output.

Comment: Problem3_1.java:84: incomparable types: java.lang.String and Problem3_1.Address
        if (p.address == a)        I know I declared it as a string, but I believe I did that wrong and it should actually be in the form of Address in type.

Comment: `void setAddress(Address s) {
  //address = s;
  
  this.address = s;
 }'

Comment: `void setAddress(Address s) {  
  this.address = s;
 }'

and override toString() method in both classes. working fine.

Test 1 passed!
Test 2 passed!
GREAT WORK! EVERYTHING PASSED!
Nice

Comment: [link](http://ideone.com/rS20uZ)

Looks good. still any incomparable types means.. please update..

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
void setAddress(Address a) {
    this.address = a;
}
```

As it stands, you are not passing any value into `setAddress`, so there is nothing for `setAddress` to do.

Comment: I tried this and now I have the error: Problem3_1.java:86: incomparable types: java.lang.String and Problem3_1.Address

Comment: and Problem3_1.java:28: incompatible types
found   : Problem3_1.Address
required: java.lang.String

Comment: Sounds like you're passing a string to `setAddress` instead of an address. How are you calling `setAddress`?

Comment: well the attribute i created is :  String address;    how would i create the address attribute to where it properly is assigned to the content of Address();.  I updated my code to what you suggested

Comment: Well, `setAddress` takes an `Address` object, not a string - that's why you're getting the error. It should be something like this: `Address a = new Address(123, "Somewhere St"); myObject.setAddress(a);`.

Comment: How would I do that without manually adding that information the 123, "Somewhere St" bit?  It has to be designed where I can pass any address and it would set the address accoringly

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Problem3_1{

String name;
int age;
int height;
int weight;    
static Address address;

public Problem3_1(String name, int age, int height,int weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height; //cm
    this.weight = weight; //kg
}

void setAddress(int number,String street) {
    address = new Address(number,street);   
}

public static void main(String [] args){
     Problem3_1 problem=new Problem3_1("Tom",28,180,78);
     problem.setAddress(4460,"new Delhi");
     System.out.println(address.getAddressNumber() +" number of street : "+address.getAddressString());

   }


 public static class Address{ 

    private int number; 
    private String street; 

    public Address(int number, String street){ 
        this.number = number; 
        this.street = street ; 
     }
    int getAddressNumber(){
      return number;
    }
    String getAddressString(){
        return street;
    }

  }
```

}

Comment: I will add the test cases to the main code, but I got this as an error now. Problem3_1.java:26: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method Address(int,java.lang.String)
location: class Problem3_1
        address = Address(number, street);
                  ^
Problem3_1.java:82: setAddress(int,java.lang.String) in Problem3_1 cannot be applied to (Problem3_1.Address)
        p.setAddress(a);

Comment: now I have changed code and runs in netbeans it works! if it helpful please up vote and accept as answer

Comment: Awesome thanks it works!  But for some reason it says that my method is in the wrong location or it can't be "applied" in running the test case.      Problem3_1.java:82: setAddress(int,java.lang.String) in Problem3_1 cannot be applied to (Problem3_1.Address)     p.setAddress(a);